# Php, MySql - insert data into two tables as key-value pair

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I'm asking for some help regarding inserting data into MySQL database from PHP form.

I've got two tables 'items' and 'attributes'. The fields are:

```
items:
SKU, name, price, type

attributes:
SKU, id, SKU, key, value
```

"SKU" is an ID for each item. And "id" is an ID for each attribute in 'attributes' .
Tables are connected via SKU column as primary/secodnary key.

I know that it's possible to insert data into several tables like that:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO items (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
        INSERT INTO attributes (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')";
```

But the problem is that my second table 'attributes' contents data as key-value pairs. The keys like 'size', 'height', 'weight' etc... And values like integers for each dimension. And I can't just type `INSERT INTO attributes (SKU, key, value) VALUES ('$SKU', '$size', '$height' ... etc)`

How is it possible to insert data into table as key-value pairs? I need to insert data for size, height, width, length, weight. Each of them has it's own input field in the form. I want to extract data from this form and insert into tables - items and attributes.

So far I've successfully inserted data into 'items' like that:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO items (SKU, name, price) VALUES ('$SKU', '$name', '$price')";
```

But I can't reach out 'attributes' table. This code doesn't work. I've tried to insert 'size' only just to check if this way works:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO attributes (SKU, key, value) VALUES ('$SKU', 'size', '$size') ON items.SKU = attributes.SKU";
```

And help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO attributes (SKU, key, value) VALUES ('$SKU', 'size', '$size') ON items.SKU = attributes.SKU";
```

1) `ON items.SKU = attributes.SKU` This syntax is incorrect and there is no need for it.

2) You are using reserved keyword "key" for column name. In order to do that you need to enclose it in backticks (`)

This sql should work:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO attributes (SKU, `key`, value) VALUES ('$SKU', 'size', '$size')";
```

If you want to insert multiple attributes, you can do it this way:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO attributes (SKU, `key`, value) VALUES
    ('$SKU', 'size', '$size'),
    ('$SKU', 'height', '$height'),
    ('$SKU', 'weight', '$weight')";
```